# Is it possible to pass a dataframe to TF/Keras that has a numpy array for each row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I'm doing a regression that is working but to improve results I wanted to add a numpy array (it represents user attributes that I preprocessed outside the application).

Here's a example of my data:

```
MPG Cylinders   Displacement    Horsepower  Weight  Acceleration    Model Year  Origin  NumpyColumn
0   18.0    8   307.0   130.0   3504.0  12.0    70  1   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
1   15.0    8   350.0   165.0   3693.0  11.5    70  1   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
2   18.0    8   318.0   150.0   3436.0  11.0    70  1   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
3   16.0    8   304.0   150.0   3433.0  12.0    70  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
4   17.0    8   302.0   140.0   3449.0  10.5    70  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
393 27.0    4   140.0   86.0    2790.0  15.6    82  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
394 44.0    4   97.0    52.0    2130.0  24.6    82  2   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
395 32.0    4   135.0   84.0    2295.0  11.6    82  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
396 28.0    4   120.0   79.0    2625.0  18.6    82  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
397 31.0    4   119.0   82.0    2720.0  19.4    82  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

Here's how to generate it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sparse

#download data
url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
column_names = ['MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Displacement', 'Horsepower', 'Weight',
                'Acceleration', 'Model Year', 'Origin']
df = pd.read_csv(url, names=column_names,
          na_values='?', comment='\t',
          sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

lenOfDF = (len(df))
#add numpy array
arr = sparse.coo_matrix(([1,1,1], ([0,1,2], [1,2,0])), shape=(lenOfDF,lenOfDF))
df['NumpyColumn'] = arr.toarray().tolist()
```

Then my model is similar to this:

```
g_input = Input(shape=[Xtrain.shape[1]])
H1 = Dense(512)(g_input)
H1r = Activation('relu')(H1)
H2 = Dense(256)(H1r)
H2r = Activation('relu')(H2)
H3 = Dense(256)(H2r)
H3r = Activation('relu')(H3)
H4 = Dense(128)(H3r)
H4r = Activation('relu')(H4)
H5 = Dense(128)(H4r)

H5r = Activation('relu')(H5)
H6 = Dense(64)(H5r)
H6r = Activation('relu')(H6)
H7 = Dense(32)(H6r)
Hr = Activation('relu')(H7)
g_V = Dense(1)(Hr)

generator = Model(g_input,g_V)
generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
```

When I call it using the dataset with the NumpyColumn(x_batch is just a split and scaled dataset of above dataframe with the numpy array passed through so it remains unchanged). I get the following error:

```
# generated = generator.predict(x_batch)                            #making prediction from the generator
generated = generator.predict(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_batch))      #making prediction from the generator
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

What am I doing wrong here? My thought is that having a array would provide the model information to make better prediction so I'm trying to test it. Is it possible to add a numpy array to a dataframe to train? Or is there an alternative approach I should be doing?

### Edit 1

Above is a sample to quickly help you understand the problem. In my case after encoding/scaling the dataframe, I have a numpy array that looks like this (it's numeric representing the catergorical encodings + two numpy arrays at the end):

```
array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 9921.0,
       20.0, 0.40457918757980704, 0.11369258150627903, 0.868421052631579,
       0.47368421052631576, 0.894736842105263, 0.06688034531010473,
       0.16160188713280013, 0.7368421052631579, 0.1673332894736842,
       0.2099143206854345, 0.3690644464300929, 0.07097828135799109,
       0.8157894736842104, 0.9210526315789473, 0.23091420289239645,
       0.08623506024464939, 0.5789473684210527, 0.763157894736842, 0.0,
       0.18421052631578946, 0.07949239000059796, 0.18763907099960708,
       0.7368421052631579, 0.2668740256483197, 0.6842105263157894,
       0.13699219747488295, 0.868421052631579, 0.868421052631579,
       0.052631349139178094, 0.6842105263157894, 0.5526315789473684,
       0.6842105263157894, 0.6842105263157894, 0.6842105263157894,
       0.7105263157894737, 0.7105263157894737, 0.7105263157894737,
       0.23684210526315788, 0.0, 0.7105263157894737, 0.5789473684210527,
       0.763157894736842, 0.5263157894736842, 0.6578947368421052,
       0.6842105263157894, 0.7105263157894737, 0.0, 0.5789473684210527,
       0.2631578947368421, 0.6842105263157894, 0.6578947368421052,
       0.42105263157894735, 0.5789473684210527, 0.42105263157894735,
       0.7368421052631579, 0.7368421052631579, 0.15207999030227856,
       0.8445892232119124, 0.2683721567016762, 0.3142850329243405,
       0.18421052631578946, 0.19132292433056333, 0.20615136344079915,
       0.14475710664724623, 0.1624920232728424, 0.6989826700898587,
       0.18421052631578946, 0.21052631578947367, 0.4793448772543646,
       0.7894736842105263, 0.682967263567459, 0.37139592674256894,
       0.21123755190149363, 0.18421052631578946, 0.6578947368421052,
       0.39473684210526316, 0.631578947368421, 0.7894736842105263,
       0.36842105263157887, 0.1863353145721346, 0.7368421052631579,
       0.26809396092240706, 0.22492185003691062, 0.1460488284639197,
       0.631578947368421, 0.15347526114630458, 0.763157894736842,
       0.2097323620058104, 0.3684210526315789, 0.631578947368421,
       0.631578947368421, 0.631578947368421, 0.6842105263157894,
       0.36842105263157887, 0.10507952765043811, 0.22418515695024185,
       0.23755698619020282, 0.22226500126902, 0.530004040377794,
       0.3421052631578947, 0.19018711711349692, 0.19629244102133708,
       0.5789473684210527, 0.10526315789473684, 0.49999999999999994,
       0.5263157894736842, 0.5263157894736842, 0.49999999999999994,
       0.1052631578947368, 0.10526315789473678, 0.5263157894736842,
       0.4736842105263157, 2013.0,
       array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.62235785, 0.        ,
       0.27049118, 0.        , 0.31094068, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.4330532 , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.2515796 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.40683705, 0.01569915, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.13090582, 0.        , 0.49955425, 0.06970194, 0.29155406,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.27342197, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.04415211, 0.        , 0.03908829, 0.        ,
       0.07673171, 0.33199945, 0.        , 0.51759815, 0.        ,
       0.4719149 , 0.4538082 , 0.13475986, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.08000553,
       0.        , 0.02991109, 0.        , 0.5051543 , 0.        ,
       0.24663273, 0.        , 0.50839704, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.05281948, 0.44884402, 0.        , 0.44542992, 0.15376966,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.39128256, 0.49497205,
       0.        , 0.        ], dtype=float32),
       array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.62235785, 0.        ,
       0.27049118, 0.        , 0.31094068, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.4330532 , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.25157961, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.40683705, 0.01569915, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.13090582, 0.        , 0.49955425, 0.06970194, 0.29155406,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.27342197, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.04415211, 0.        , 0.03908829, 0.        ,
       0.07673171, 0.33199945, 0.        , 0.51759815, 0.        ,
       0.47191489, 0.45380819, 0.13475986, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.08000553,
       0.        , 0.02991109, 0.        , 0.50515431, 0.        ,
       0.24663273, 0.        , 0.50839704, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.05281948, 0.44884402, 0.        , 0.44542992, 0.15376966,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.39128256, 0.49497205,
       0.        , 0.        ])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Look at `xbatch`, as  you extract it from the dataframe (not as you feed it to the frame).  What is its `dtype` and `shape`.  My guess it is a 1d object dtype, containing arrays, not a 2d numeric array.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj - I'm not sure how to check if it's 1d or 2d, The dtype of df before encoding it is - Length: 134, dtype: object and shape is (159921, 134).  All my columns type are either float64 or category except my numpy arrays, those two are objects.

Comment: Do you even know what we mean by an array's `shape`?

Comment: @hpaulj No, I thought you meant the df's shape.If I do df["NumpyColumn"][0].shape I get (77,) and type for it is <class 'numpy.ndarray'> .  Is that what your asking?

Comment: So it's a 1d array of objects.  The objects happen to be lists, but that doesn't matter to `torch`.  However constructed, the dataframe put one array in each `cell`.  `np.stack(xbatch)` might work to join the individual arrays into one 2d array.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj I’m not using torch. I’m using tensorflow. When joining the dataframe with the vectors should I being doing something different ? Or converting the column type before hand ?

Comment: You are trying to pass a nested list/array objects as a feature to convert to tensor. That's the reason for the error. You can handle it at pandas level by simply converting the n length lists/arrays to n columns (check the second method below). However, usually, when working with such columns, you ideally want to process them differently in the network (such as pass this column into an LSTM for example). Therefore an ideal way is to have a multi-input model. Check the solution for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem:

You are trying to pass nested list/array objects as a feature to convert to tensor. That's the reason for the error. You can handle it at `pandas` level by simply converting the n length lists/arrays to n columns (check solution 2). However, usually, when working with such columns, you ideally want to process them differently in the network (such as pass this column into an LSTM for example). Therefore an ideal way is to have a `multi-input model`, which is usually how we work with these features in the industry (check solution 1).

---

#### Solution 1: Solving this via Multi-inputs

This is a fairly common problem especially when we are working with multiple sequences of data or multiple encodings.

One straightforward method of solving this is by creating separate inputs for each encoding.

1. (Assuming X_train has 9 columns) Pass 8 columns out of the 9 to the first input, and the encoding (column with list/array) as a separate input.
2. Concatenate these to create an `8+398` length tensor which now passes through the computation graph.
3. The single series with lists can be converted to a tensor/np.array by `np.array(df.column.tolist())`. This will convert the `(398,)` length series with lists to a `(398, 398)` shaped NumPy array.
4. Now, you can handle the features and the encodings separately as well before concatenating them and passing them through Dense layers. E.g passing the second input via LSTM layers.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils, activations

g_input = layers.Input(shape=(8,))       #<--------
np_input = layers.Input(shape=(398,))    #<--------
x = layers.concatenate([g_input, np_input])
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
g_V = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

generator = Model([g_input,np_input],g_V)
generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

utils.plot_model(generator, show_layer_names=False, show_shapes=True)

print('')
print('RESHAPING DATA TO - (398,8) and (398,398)')
generator.predict([df.drop('NumpyColumn',1).to_numpy(), 
                   np.array(df['NumpyColumn'].tolist())]).shape
```

```
RESHAPING DATA TO - (398,8) and (398,398)
(398, 1)
```

[image]

---

#### Solution 2: Solving this via Pandas

If however, you don't want the encoding to be separate and are simply going to use it as a flattened feature along with other features, then you can simply just flatten the data frame over axis=1 to create `8+398` columns and then convert it to tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils, activations

g_input = layers.Input(shape=(406,))       #<---------
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(g_input)
x = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
g_V = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

generator = Model(g_input,g_V)
generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

utils.plot_model(generator, show_layer_names=False, show_shapes=True)

print('')
print('RESHAPING DATA TO - (398, 406)')
ddf = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:-1], df.NumpyColumn.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1) #<-----
generator.predict(tf.convert_to_tensor(ddf)).shape #<-----
```

```
RESHAPING DATA TO - (398, 406)
(398, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Akshay - This answer helped me understand - multi-input models. Many thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: glad to help, anytime.

Comment: Glad to see that solved your question. Do also mark the answer so that others can benefit from the same :) thanks!